# False statement about a continuous and non negative function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity

It was asked in University of Hyderabad exam(2017).

I have shown 2nd and 3rd Statments to be true with the help of "Intermediate Value Theorem for Integrals".

But i can't reason why the statement 1 is false?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral can be made as small as you please. To see this, consider the family of functions $f_\delta:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$f_\delta(x)=\begin{cases}  \:\frac{100}{\delta}(x-(c-\delta)) &\text{$c-\delta\leqslant x\leqslant c$}\\ \: \frac{100}{\delta}((c+\delta)-x) &\text{$c\leqslant x\leqslant c+\delta$}\\ \:\: 0 &\text{elsewhere} \end{cases}$$
with $0<\delta<c$ (these functions basically have a spike centered at $c$). We have
$$\int_0^1 f(x)\:dx=100\cdot\delta$$
and $\delta$ can be made as small as you please.

Answer (score 0):

Why would it be true ? You can very well design a continuous function that is $0$ in $99.999\%$ of the integration interval and grows to $100$ somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a counter example: consider the function $f:[0,1]\to[0,\infty)$ defined as follows.

$f(0)=100$. For $t\in[0, \frac{1}{200}]$, set $f(t)=-100\cdot200\cdot t+100$ and for $t\geq \frac{1}{200}$ set $f(t)=0$. To convince yourself that $f$ is continuous, sketch it!

Now $\int_0^1f(t)dt=\int_0^{1/200}f(t)dt=\int_0^{1/200}(-100\cdot200\cdot t+100)dt=-\frac{100\cdot 200}{2\cdot 200^2}+\frac{1}{2}=-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}<\frac{1}{2}.$